# Чистота Haskell и функциональное программирование

Tags: haskell, lisp, scheme, функциональное-программирование

Интересует функциональная парадигма, и вот даже немного Scheme пробую. Но вот встал такой вопрос. В Haskell с помощью IO можно реализовывать императивное поведение. Тогда не понятно, насколько он чист. Функциональное программирование пошло из лямбда-исчислением, так вот идея об отсутствии побочных эффектов пошла оттуда? Очень интересная и , на мой взгляд, правильная парадигма, но как она вообще могла прийти в голову, если она не позволяет иметь какую либо связь с миром, т.к. ввод-вывод - изменяемое состояние.

Comment: Как насчет матиматических функций и физических законов, механики, электродинамики, химии ... финкции это прирогатива не биологического мира что есть 99.999...%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haskell чист, потому что в ним нельзя скрыть операции ввода-вывода и других изменяемых состояние мира от системы типов, т.е. каждая упомянутая операция накладывает опечаток в цепи вывода типов. Иначе говоря, функции использующие монады, сами по себе не делают ничего, кроме возвращения значений, а "нечистые" операции выполняются "за кулисами".

Comment: Если очень хочется, то можно и скрыть, например, с помощью `unsafePerformIO`.